# SQL- Get the next row based off a grouping

Tags: sql

```
CUST    Date/Time          Status    Status_Type
23      10.22.93 12:00     Good      GD   
23      10.23.93 12:00     GoodY     GDY
23      10.24.93 12:00     GoodG     GDG
77      10.22.93 12:00     Good      GD
```

What I need:

```
CUST    Date/Time          Status    Status_Type    Next_Step_Status       Next_Step_Type
23      10.22.93 12:00     Good      GD             GoodY                  GDY
23      10.23.93 12:00     GoodY     GDY            GoodG                  GDG
23      10.24.93 12:00     GoodG     GDG            NULL                   NULL
77      10.22.93 12:00     Good      GD             NULL                   NULL
```

Is there a way to get the next value for a row based off a grouping (CUST)?

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only the database you are really using.

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of the `LEAD()` function.

Comment: Wait... you say you want the "next row", but then you say the "previous row". Which one is it?

Comment: I am sorry it is the next row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(status) over (partition by cust order by datetime) as next_status,
       lead(status_type) over (partition by cust order by datetime) as next_status_type
from t;
```

Comment: Truly a legend.